# .htaccess rewrite rule: remove slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Current .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)$ /r.php?catname=$1&subcatname=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ /r.php?catname=$1&subcatname=$2&page=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)$ /r.php?catname=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ /r.php?catname=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

My output is currently:

```
www.domain.com/$catname                  =>      www.domain.com/blog
www.domain.com/$catname/&subcatname/         =>      www.domain.com/blog/extra/
www.domain.com/$catname/&subcatname/3/       =>      www.domain.com/blog/extra/3/
www.domain.com/$catname/2/        =>      www.domain.com/blog/extra/2/
```

I want my output to be:

```
www.domain.com/$catname                       =>      www.domain.com/blog
www.domain.com/$catname/&subcatname              =>      www.domain.com/blog/extra
www.domain.com/$catname/&subcatname/&page        =>      www.domain.com/blog/extra/1
www.domain.com/$catname/&page                   =>      www.domain.com/blog/1
```

I would like it so none of the urls have a trailing slash.

Comment: Please let me know if it's doesn't work

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0):

Update your RewriteRule  as following hopefully you will get expected output:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)$ /r.php?catname=$1&subcatname=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)$ /r.php?   catname=$1&subcatname=$2&page=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)$ /r.php?catname=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)$ /r.php?catname=$1&page=$2 [L]
```